# Providing uncompressed buffer interface from compressed file

Tags: python, buffer, gzip

How to provide a uncompressed `buffer` interface from a compressed file (format not limited)?

I'm expecting a library that `open`s (or `mmap`s) a compressed file, and provides a regular `buffer` as if it isn't compressed. I can then work on the `buffer` (e.g. with `numpy`) without caring about the compression. The changes written to the `buffer` should be flushed back to the file.

File-system level compression can obviously do that, but is there any method that doesn't require a special fs?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that there's anything available that keeps recompressing the file as you mess with the memory buffer.

However all you need to do is decompress your file into memory, have your way with it in memory, and then compress and write it back out to the file.

Comment: What about read only? Dynamic seeking and decompressing? So that when I want to do a bisect, I can complete in `log(n)`?

Comment: No. In general, compressed data cannot be randomly accessed.